# How do I resize a checkbox drawable to fit correctly?

Tags: android, checkbox, drawable

I'm developing an app in Android, and since I'm using a dark background, the checkboxes are not visible so I need to use a drawable, I have created a 45 x 45 px image, if I test it in a Nexus 5, the image looks big, and it looks bigger in a lower resolution phone, this is the output:

[image: [1]:] https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjBDV.png

What's the recommended size for a drawable checkbox? how can I fit it accordingly to different resolutiones? thank you!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the suggestions I ended up using a 9patch image, however, I want to double check if my assumption is correct, since I need to resize the whole checkbox, the boundaries should be on the edges of the images right? I'm not selecting the transparent area:

[image]

Would that be ok? I already tested it in a Nexus 5 and in an emulator (320 x 480), and it looks ok, just double checking, thanks!

Comment: What folder are your using for store image, hdpi, xhdpi, or xxhdpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is information about sizes in Android: http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

So good size is about 32dp for `CheckBox` and you can make the image 9-patch. So minimum pixel size gets automatically scaled to fit and look good.

For pixel sizes check this: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html